# Change Title Color in Highchart

Tags: javascript, css

My question is how to change x & y axis - font (title/lables) color when the background color change (dark or light bgcolor).

I know how to change the x / y axis title color as in http://jsfiddle.net/4rTBY/1454/

I can get the background color when the page load using

```
var bgclr = window.getComputedStyle( document.body ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

but lets assume we dont know when the bgcolor will change -> we dont know the triggered/function that change the bgcolor

how do I change the font color?

thank you very much for your time

Comment: I assume you need to change theme right?

Comment: aha, you got me. yes the reason to do this is to change the theme (manually). but I was stuck because I cant access the function that being called when the 'dark/light theme' button is clicked. so I wonder if there is a way to do this without knowing the function

Comment: have you try https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

Comment: yes I have visited that page. and yes we can change the x/y axis title color to something else, but for it to be triggered (to change color) we need to refresh (f5) the page. the goal is to change the font color without refreshing the page (without f5).
anyway thanks for coming back and trying to help :)